# $\mathfrak{m}^k$ is maximal if $\mathfrak{m}$ is

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian, artinian

Can I say that in an Artinian Ring $A$, if $\frak{m}$ is maximal, then $\mathfrak{m}^k$ is maximal $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$?

This question arise because I would like to conclude that $\mathfrak{m_1}^k \cdots\mathfrak{m_n}^k = (0) \Rightarrow A $  is artinian $\iff$ it is noetherian. But I know that this is valid only if the product is a finite product of maximal ideals.

My attempt of a proof is: let's suppose that $\mathfrak{m}^k$ is not maximal, then $\exists \mathfrak{a} \subset A$ proper ideal such that $\mathfrak{m}^k \subset \mathfrak{a}$. So given that every maximal ideal is prime $\sqrt{\mathfrak{m}^k} = \mathfrak{m} \subset \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}} $ which is proper. Contradiction. Is it right?.

Comment: This only is true if $\mathfrak m$ is idempotent, as $\mathfrak m^k ⊆ \mathfrak m$. Surely, you’ll find counterexamples. However, $\mathfrak m_1^k · … · \mathfrak m_n^k$ is still just a finite product of maximal ideals if $\mathfrak m_1, …, \mathfrak m_n$ are maximal.

Comment: @k.stm thank you! Why do you say that $\mathfrak{m_1}^k\cdots \mathfrak{m_n}^k$ is a finite product of maximal ideals?

Comment: Think about it. You may be overtired or just be temporarily blinded. It’ll come to you soon.

Comment: @k.stm got it. thank you.